# Javascript Date constructor odd behavior

Tags: javascript

I am getting an odd behavior if I pass the Date constructor just a date string. Example:

```
    <div>Date 1: <span id="mydate1"></span></div>
    <div>Date 2: <span id="mydate2"></span></div>
    <div>Date 3: <span id="mydate3"></span></div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("mydate1").innerHTML = (new Date("2022-06-28 20:32:00")).toString();
        document.getElementById("mydate2").innerHTML = (new Date("2022-06-28")).toString();
        document.getElementById("mydate3").innerHTML = (new Date("2022-06-28 00:00:00")).toString();
    </script>
```

This results in the following:

```
Date 1: Tue Jun 28 2022 20:32:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Date 2: Mon Jun 27 2022 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Date 3: Tue Jun 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Date 1 works as I would expect. But why are Date 2 and 3 different?  With just a date string, it seems to be inferring the date is in UTC, where as with a time field it seems to assume it is in my locale time.

Any thoughts?  I can work around it by appending the 00:00:00 text.

Comment: "*But why are Date 2 and 3 different?*" answered by "*With just a date string, it seems to be inferring the date is in UTC, where as with a time field it seems to assume it is in my locale time.*"

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#date_string)?

Comment: Ah.  Helps to read the fine print. Still odd, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained in the [documentation of `Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#date_string), when the argument is a date string:

> Date-only strings (e.g. `"1970-01-01"`) are treated as UTC, while date-time strings (e.g. `"1970-01-01T12:00"`) are treated as local.